# VBA retorna string de data errada

Tags: string, microsoft-excel, vba, data

Fiz um código para retornar um string do primeiro dia do mês atua:

```
Dia = "1/" & CStr(Month(Now)) & "/" & CStr(Year(Now))
```

depois eu colo ele numa célula

```
Cells(rowx,colx).value = Dia
```

o valor colado troca de posição o dia com o mês, por algum motivo... 
Existe algum outro modo de conseguir esse número, ele devolver "2/1/2016"?

Comment: Tentou `Cells(rowx, coly).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/aaaa"` ?

Comment: tentei, consegui resolver de outra maneira, mandei colar só o mês e ano, quando é colado no excel ele coloca o 1/ na frente sozinho

Comment: Saquei. Publique sua solução como resposta pra ajudar a próxima vítima. :)

Comment: Primeiramente, você tem certeza que não há um erro no seu código? Digo isso porque uma função que vc usa parece errada (está `years`, mas eu creio que deveria ser `year`). Em segundo lugar, o motivo da escolha automatizada é o idioma do Excel que você usa. Em inglês americano o mês é exibido primeiro em uma data. Aqui, no meu Excel em português, o seu código (com `year`), funciona corretamente e exibe: `1/2/2016`.

Comment: eu redigitei rapidamente o código aqui, e sou dislexico, nao percebi que tinha colocado o s la, vou editar para remover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui com uma gambiarra, ao colocar a variável somente como

```
Dia = CStr(Month(Now)) & "/" & CStr(Year(Now))
```

o excel coloca a data com a formatação da célula e atribuiu o valor correto